# Generics with Hibernate when should I have to use criteria?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics, dao

I tried to use generics with my code.
I have Dao that get info from BD :

```
@Component
public class BasicDAOImpl<T> implements BasicDAO<T> {
    private Class<T> type;

    public BasicDAOImpl(Class<T> type) {this.type = type;
    }

    public BasicDAOImpl() {
    }

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionfactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<T> getAllByKey(int id) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            Session session = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(type);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("parentid", id));
           list.addAll(criteria.list());
        }catch (HibernateException e){}

        return list;
    }
```

And I have : 
 WorkoutDAOImpl  extende BasicDAOImpl

```
public class WorkoutDAOImpl extends BasicDAOImpl<Workout> implements WorkoutDAO {}
```

Bean:

```
@Bean
public WorkoutDAO workoutDAO(){
    return new WorkoutDAOImpl();
}
```

I write in my code:

```
workoutDAO.getAllByKey(int 2)
```

and get error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

in 
`Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(type)`.

Why?
If write `Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Workout.class)`, then dont get any errors.

PS/ Sorry or my english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Workout.class` isn't passed to `BasicDAOImpl` from your `WorkoutDAOImpl` so `Class<T> type` isn't initialized and you get `NullPointerException`. Add no-argument constructor:

```
public class WorkoutDAOImpl extends BasicDAOImpl<Workout> implements WorkoutDAO {

    public WorkoutDAOImpl() {
        super(Workout.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call One Parameter Constructor of **BasicDAOImpl** class in order to set initialize the **type** variable.

1. Create a No-argument Constructor in **WorkoutDAOImpl** class and call to Super Class Constructor i.e. **BasicDAOImpl** as follows:

```
public class WorkoutDAOImpl extends BasicDAOImpl implements WorkoutDAO {
      WorkoutDAOImpl(){
       super(Workout.class);
      }

    }
```

Though, You can also use Reflection to solve it. But, in the way you want to do it, you have to invoke BasicDAOImpl's Constructor explicitly.